# How can I tell how many worker dynos I'm using on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, worker, hirefire

I'm using HireFireApp to autoscale my web and worker dynos on Heroku. However, when I navigate to the Resque app on my application it says

"0 of 46 Workers Working"

Does this mean that I'm using 46 worker dynos???

Update:

Running heroku ps shows:

```
web.1     up for 21m       bundle exec thin start -p $PORT       
worker.1  starting for 1s  bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE..
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the command line in your heroku app have a look at the output of

`heroku ps`

that will show you how many workers you are running.

Comment: and in HirefireApp you can set a limit to the max number of workers/dynos it can scale you to use if you never want to go beyond a certain number.